# MUI Collapsible table squashed into one cell when expanded

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use MUI table with Collapse to expand/collapse rows. However when using collapse, the the expanded rows are squashed into one cell.
How can I align the cells to the parent table?

```
 export default function App() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell />
          <TableCell>Header 1</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Header 2</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Header 3</TableCell>
          <TableCell>Header 4</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}>Expand</TableCell>
          <TableCell>A</TableCell>
          <TableCell>B</TableCell>
          <TableCell>C</TableCell>
          <TableCell>D</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell>E</TableCell>
            <TableCell>F</TableCell>
            <TableCell>G</TableCell>
            <TableCell>H</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </Collapse>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
};
```

Removing the Collapse results in the correct format.
e.g. current state is:
[image]

Desired result (after expanding is)[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `<Collapse />` component is a div, and divs can't be wrapped around table rows. You need to make a second table inside the Collapse, and align the cells so they are all the same size.

[Codesandbox demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-shape-k6et7?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: That just expands and add an entirely new table under the existing table. Which means that if you have more than one row, the expansion won't be under which ever row that you want expanded.

Comment: @Jim True. The expantion won't be under each row.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it:

```
<Table>
    <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell padding="checkbox"/>
          <TableCell>Area name</TableCell>
          <TableCell>2011</TableCell>
          <TableCell>2012</TableCell>
          <TableCell>2013</TableCell>
          <TableCell>2014</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell padding="checkbox">
            <IconButton
              size="small"
              onClick={() => setOpen(prev => !prev)}
            >
              {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon/> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon/>}
            </IconButton>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell component="th">Paris</TableCell>
          <TableCell>1000</TableCell>
          <TableCell>2000</TableCell>
          <TableCell>3000</TableCell>
          <TableCell>4000</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow sx={{ visibility: open ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}>
          <TableCell padding="checkbox"/>
          <TableCell component="th">1er arondissement</TableCell>
          <TableCell>100</TableCell>
          <TableCell>200</TableCell>
          <TableCell>300</TableCell>
          <TableCell>400</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
```

The trick being `sx={{ visibility: open ? 'visible' : 'collapse' }}` on the TableRow you want to be collapsible.

Answer (score 0):

I just tweaked above answer so that each rows can be expanded or collapsed on clicking.

```js
import {
  Collapse,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
} from '@mui/material'
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const Row = () => {
    const [exp, setExp] = useState(false)

    return (
      <>
        <Table>
          <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell onClick={() => setExp(!exp)}>Expand</TableCell>
              <TableCell colSpan={4}></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
        <Collapse in={exp} timeout='auto' unmountOnExit>
          <Table>
            <TableBody>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell />
                <TableCell>E</TableCell>
                <TableCell>F</TableCell>
                <TableCell>G</TableCell>
                <TableCell>H</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Collapse>
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell>Header 1</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Header 2</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Header 3</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Header 4</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
      </Table>
      {Array(5)
        .fill()
        .map(item => (
          <Row />
        ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-borg-uulef6?file=/src/App.js)